# For background download should i use service?

Tags: android, background, download, android-activity, android-service

i'm developing my first Android app and i created a class (not Activity) that downloads a JSON file and writes content to SQLite database at every start-up of the application.
I then use an instance of this class in the main activity class.
If the download takes few seconds the home page of my app hangs on a blank screen.

Do you think i should use service instead of a class to handle download and writing of the db?
Could it be a good idea? If it could, what are the advantages?

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing to a database I would recommend using an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

The intent service runs in it's own thread.

When the download is complete you can use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to notify the activity.
It could also work with [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).

Answer (score 2):

I also wanted to download the  list of images in background so I used [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)s with `SharedPreferences` and I also Used `AQuery` With the `Service`.Here the `ConnectionDetector` is my Java class which checks the Internet Connection is available or not. It works for me. I hope it will give u some help.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

String f;
String path;
File file;
Bitmap bm;
String url1;
ArrayList<String> url_img;
AQuery aq;
int count = 1;
String val;
ArrayList<String> completed_url_list;
ArrayList<Integer> _index;
FileOutputStream out;
static ArrayList<String> list;
private Thread updateTask = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (count < url_img.size()) {

            try {
                Log.e("Counter", "" + count);
                val = url_img.get(count).toString();
                final AjaxCallback<Bitmap> cb = new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void callback(String url, Bitmap bm,
                            AjaxStatus status) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("url is" + url);
                            String urll = url.substring(url
                                    .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                            Log.e("Image name", "" + urll);
                            System.out.println("url111" + urll);
                            File f = new File(path + urll);
                            f.createNewFile();
                            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
                            try {
                                out = new FileOutputStream(f);

                                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40,
                                        out);
                                if (out != null) {
                                    out.flush();
                                    out.close();
                                    Log.e("download", "Complete");
                                    completed_url_list.add(url);
                                    System.out
                                            .println("Completed Dowmload Image"
                                                    + completed_url_list);
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                boolean del_file = f.delete();
                                if (del_file == true){
                                    Log.e("File", "deleted");
                                    System.out.println("exception");
                                    }
                                else{
                                    System.out.println("file not deleted");
                                }
                            } finally {
                                out.close();
                                if (bm != null) {
                                    bm.recycle();
                                    bm = null;
                                }
                                System.gc();
                            }
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                };
                final AQuery aq = new AQuery(getApplicationContext());
                aq.ajax(val, Bitmap.class, 0, cb);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            count++;
        }

    }
});

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {
        url_img = getArrayList();
        completed_url_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        _index = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        aq = new AQuery(MyService.this);
        System.out.println("I am in super");
        if (url_img.size() > 0) {
            updateTask.start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    super.onCreate();


    try {
        System.out.println("Service Creating");
        f = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        path = f + "/HRI3mages/";
        file = new File(path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try {
        for (int index = 0; index < completed_url_list.size(); index++) {
            for (int index1 = 0; index1 < url_img.size(); index1++) {
                if (completed_url_list.get(index).equals(
                        url_img.get(index1))) {
                    _index.add(index1);
                }
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(_index, new MyIntComparable());
        System.out.println("next_download" + _index);
        for(int index=0;index<_index.size();index++){
            url_img.remove(index);
        }
        System.out.println("After_Deletion_of_Image"+url_img);
        _addArray(url_img);
        updateTask.interrupt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    System.out.println("Service destroy");
    super.onDestroy();

}
public class MyIntComparable implements Comparator<Integer>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return (o1>o2 ? -1 : (o1==o2 ? 0 : 1));
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> getArrayList() {
    ArrayList<String> list_url = new ArrayList<String>();
    SharedPreferences SharedPref = getSharedPreferences("SSO", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int size = SharedPref.getInt("list_size", 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        list_url.add(SharedPref.getString("list_" + i, ""));
    }
    System.out.println(list_url);
    return list_url;
}
public void _addArray(ArrayList<String> list) {
    SharedPreferences SharedPref = getSharedPreferences("SSO", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SharedPref.edit();

    int size = list.size();
    editor.putInt("list_size", size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        editor.putString("list_" + i, list.get(i));
    }
    editor.commit();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use an AsyncTask.
This will do the work in a background thread, so if it takes long your screen won't hang.
While the work is in progress, you can show a ProgressDialog (optional) to inform the user. You can also add a button to that ProgressDialog to cancel the task if needed.

See this: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

In this case I prefer an AsyncTask and not a Service so it seems easier and simpler to do what you want.

Good luck =)